# WP 3.1 custom post type permlinks

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, customization

I know there is alot of discussion about the CPT and permlinks together with the 404.
I did not found a solution though I am close.
It would be great if someone could assist me to get it working.

Ok what I did is:

```
    function post_type_services() 
{    
    register_post_type( 'services',
                array( 
                'label' => __('Services'), 
                'singular_name' => __( 'Service' ),
                'capability_type' => 'post',
                'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'service','with_front' => FALSE),
                'public'  => true, 
                'show_ui' => true ) );     

    flush_rewrite_rules( false );
    }
add_action('init', 'post_type_services');
```

I added a CPT for services. I added a slug and I also added `flush_rewrite_rules(false)` as suggested in many blog posts.

I turned on Permlinks with the settings `/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%` 
I added a file `single-services.php` which contains following content

```
   <?php 
    get_header(); 
?>
<div class="content">
    <div class="content_resize">
        <div class="mainbar">
    <?php query_posts('post_type=services'); ?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="article">
                <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
                <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyten' ), 'after' => '' ) ); ?>
                <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentyten' ), '', '' ); ?>
    </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar">
            <div class="gadget">
                <h2>Auswahl</h2>
                <div class="clr"></div>
                    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'menu_class' => 'sb_menu', 'theme_location' => 'leftmain' ) ); ?>
            </div>
            <?php get_sidebar(); ?> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
<div class="fbg">
    <div class="fbg_resize">
            <div class="footer">
                <?php get_footer(); ?>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So far so good. What I want is. if I navigate to http://www.mydomain.com/service I would like to see my list of services and when I click on a single service I want to display the single service.

What I do get right now is when I navigate to http://www.mydomain.com/service. I get a 404 but when I visit http://www.mydomain.com/service/my-first-service I see the list of services...

What did I do wrong? How can I get a list of services when I visit http://www.mydomain.com/service ?

P.S.: I use the starkers base template to generate my own...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the following to your `register_post_type()` array:

`'has_archive' => 'service'`

Comment: Glad it was a simple fix! :)